# FAST Search & Managed Metadata Service

Tags: fast-search, search, managed-metadata

We have a FAST Search application set up that is indexing data in an external datastore.  We have a large number of FAST Keywords and Synonyms applied directly within the FAST setup, but we would like to share those terms using the Managed Metadata Service.

Is there any way to get FAST Search to use keywords from MMS when working with external documents?  It seems like it would be trivial to do it if we were indexing data through SP Lists, but that isn't the route we want to go right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by sharing terms?

- Do you want to pushed MMS terms into a property extractor? If so, you need to write code to keep the MMS and the property extractor synchronised
- Do you want to merge a field (i.e. Modified By) from two sources? If so, you do this via managed properties.

Need a bit more info to help out.

Comment: What I mean by sharing is that I want to define a term set once in MMS, and then not re-define it as a set of FAST Keywords.

I am not looking to go as far as the property extractors (yet, anyway), but just the FAST Keyword list for synonym usage.

I think you are likely right in that I will have to write something to keep the two of them synchronized unfortunately...

Comment: Finally accepted that we need to write something to keep thin in sync...